# TextMate GetBundle stopped working in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, textmate

It seems that I am no longer able to Get Bundles using TextMate after upgrading to Snow Leopard.

I get the following error message. Googling shows no solutions. I have updated to the latest GetBundle via svn to no avail.

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle: dlopen(/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper - /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle
    from /Users/jauderho/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/Support/getBundles.rb:4
```

Comment: Are you using GetBundle or GetBundles? These are not the same.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Try updating GetBundles: 
See, for example: http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try upgrading the GetBundle bundle itself? I thought they stopped using SVN, so you may be pulling from the wrong repository.

http://github.com/textmate/getbundle.tmbundle

Comment: According to this blog entry, I should be able to pull from either. I tried switching to the git based repo but did not get further progress.